# How to eliminate 'Only index into arrays using constant expressions' warning?

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

I've written a kd-tree template, it's parameter being a natural number K.

As part of the template, I've written the following function to compute the distance between two points (kd_point is an alias for std::array)

```
template <unsigned K>
float kd_tree<K>::DistanceSq(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q)
{
    float Sum = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
        Sum += (P[i] - Q[i]) * (P[i] - Q[i]);

    return Sum;
}
```

I've turned "Enable C++ Core Check (Release)" on, and it gives me said warning. Is there a right way to write this routine to eliminate the warning?

Comment: Basically it means don't use raw `for` loops, use ranged `for` loops. I don't see how it could apply to your case, but maybe someone else could shed a light.

Comment: I know how to write a range for loop to access each element of either kd-points.

How do I write a range for loop to access both in order to calculate the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention in comments that your `kd_point`'s support range based iteration (so I assume can return iterators), you can re-write the function without the raw loop. Use named algorithms from the standard library instead:

```
template <unsigned K>
float kd_tree<K>::DistanceSq(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q)
{
  return std::inner_product(
    begin(P), end(P), begin(Q), 0.0f, std::plus<float>{},
    [](float pi, float qi) {
      return (pi - qi)*(pi - qi);
    }
  );
}
```

The standard library would be exempt from the warning, of course. If the (in this case) marginal benefit of replacing a raw loop by a named operation doesn't appeal to you, consider that if you ever come back to this code with a C++17 enabled compiler, you'll be able to almost effortlessly parallelize it:

```
template <unsigned K>
float kd_tree<K>::DistanceSq(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q)
{
  return std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par, // Parallel execution enabled 
    begin(P), end(P), begin(Q), 0.0f, std::plus<float>{},
    [](float pi, float qi) {
      return (pi - qi)*(pi - qi);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or does c++ get less readable with every edition?

Comment: @Rotem - The standard library had `std::inner_product` since the beginning. Trust me, a lambda makes this far more readable than it could have been. And the named operation in place of a raw loop is easier to "get". I mean, yeah, there's a fair bit of boiler-plate, but it's kinda obvious now that it does some sort of inner product operation, no?

Comment: As kd point is an std::array, it has range iterators and the code would work. Thank you!

I get the logic behind this, but kind of agree with Rotem - this kind of code requires getting used to.

Comment: @UriRaz - Certainly agree with you on that. This particular code doesn't exeamplify it much, but once you start composing algorithms onto each other, the raw loop quickly gets left behind, despite its immediate simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

[Answer by StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366991/261217) is probably the most suitable C++ way to solve this particular task.

I would like to add that in general, if you want to iterate not over one, but over two sequences simultaneously, you can use "secret overload of [`boost::range::for_each`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/range/algorithm_ext/for_each.hpp)", accepting two ranges:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/for_each.hpp>

template <unsigned K>
float kd_tree<K>::DistanceSq(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q)
{
    float Sum = 0;

    boost::range::for_each(P, Q, [&Sum](float p, float q) 
    { 
      Sum += (p - q) * (p - q);
    });        

    return Sum;
}
```

Note that similarly to standard algorithms, this algorithm is header-only and won't bring any library dependency to your code.